# How can i make a theme responsive or the width adjust for all browsers and devices? MyBB

Tags: responsive-design, width, forum, mybb

I want to make my theme so it will fit all browsers and mobile devices and be fully responsive, how can i do this im using forum software MyBB my forum link is: http://deepblood.com/

Help me please i need this so i can official launch my site.

If anybody would assist me with this issue i would be most grateful :)

Forum: http://deepblood.com/

Software: MyBB

How can i make the theme responsive for all browsers and devices?

Answer (score 1):

Let me go from simple to complex.

1. Use free responsive mybb theme.

   - [MyResponisve](http://community.mybb.com/mods.php?action=view&pid=303)
2. Use paid responsive mybb themes

   - [Aadya Responsive Mybb Professional Theme](http://chowsblog.com/aadya-responsive-mybb-professional-theme/)
   - [MyBBPro](https://www.mybb.de/erweiterungen/18x/themes/mybbpro/)
3. Customizing a non-responsive theme. (most probably, you are interested in this). 
   Use Chrome Inspect Elements or Firefox Firebug to see the width of div elements and change their fixed value in pixels to percent denoted by % on css. I recommend you to create a custom css file to put on the template. eg.

   ```
   @media (max-width: 768px) {  
     .warpper { 
       width: 100%; 
     }
   }
   ```

   The above css code only targets browser/device width of 768px and below. To read more, follow [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/). 
   You can also use [Responsive Mobile Menu](http://responsivemobilemenu.com/en/). Then you have to check and make each page responsive until you find no component that is not responsive.